# Filtering + using the sum function using multiple conditions for a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| Student Name | Absents | Absent Week | Excused or Unexcused | Reported by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Henry | 2 | week 4 | Unexcused | Excused |
| Elizabeth | 2 | week 4 | Unexcused | Parent |
| Elizabeth | 3 | week 4 | Unexcused | Parent |
| Sara | 4 | week 4 | Unexcused | Parent |
| Elizabeth | 5 | week 3 | Excused | Parent |
| Henry | 1 | week 1 | Unexcused | Student |
| Sara | 2 | week 4 | Unexcused | Parent |

I need to create a column called '**Total Unexcused Absents for week 4 Reported by Parent**'
Where I am applying the following:

- Summing of the absents
- Grouping by the Student Name
- Excused or Unexcused = Unexcused
- Reported By = parent

I have tried the following:

df['Total Unexcused Absents for week 4 Reported by Parent'] = df.loc[(df['Reported by'] == 'Parent') & (df['Excused or Unexcused'] == 'Unexcused') & df['Absents'].groupby(df['Student Name']).transform('sum')]

Ideally I want the data to look like this:

| Student Name | Absents | Absent Week | Excused or Unexcused | Reported by | Total Unexcused Absents for week 4 Reported by Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Henry | 2 | week 4 | Unexcused | Excused | Student |
| Elizabeth | 2 | week 4 | Unexcused | Parent | 5 |
| Sara | 2 | week 4 | Unexcused | Parent | 4 |
| Elizabeth | 5 | week 3 | Excused | Parent | 0 |
| Henry | 1 | week 1 | Unexcused | Student | 0 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is count `5` or `4` in last column?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df = (df.assign(**{'Total Unexcused Absents for week 4 Reported by Parent': 
                        (df['Reported by'] == 'Parent') & 
                        (df['Excused or Unexcused'] == 'Unexcused')})
        .groupby(['Student Name','Absent Week','Excused or Unexcused','Reported by'], 
                 as_index=False, sort=False)
        .sum()
        .reindex(df.columns.tolist() + ['Total Unexcused Absents for week 4 Reported by Parent'], axis=1)
       )
print (df)
  Student Name  Absents Absent Week Excused or Unexcused Reported by  \
0        Henry        2      week 4            Unexcused     Excused   
1    Elizabeth        5      week 4            Unexcused      Parent   
2         Sara        6      week 4            Unexcused      Parent   
3    Elizabeth        5      week 3              Excused      Parent   
4        Henry        1      week 1            Unexcused     Student   

   Total Unexcused Absents for week 4 Reported by Parent  
0                                                  0      
1                                                  2      
2                                                  2      
3                                                  0      
4                                                  0
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to explicitly say that I want to sum up the 'Absents' column? And do we have to group by all the other attributes in the 4th line?